# Minimum Index of a Sequence given a certain condition

Tags: notation

Let $S = \langle 1,3,5,8,13 \rangle$ be a sequence.

Whicho notation could I use to denote the "minimum position of $S$ where $s_k \geq 5$? In this example, the function would return 3 (the position of 5 in the sequence).

I tried to formalize it in this way:
$\min\limits_{0<k<|S|} | s_k \geq 5$, but I'm not sure if it makes sense.

Do you guys have any suggestion?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your notation does not really make sense. What you want is probably $$\min \{ k\mid s_k \geq 5\}$$ or $$\min \{ k \in \mathbb{N} \mid 1 \leq k \leq |S|, s_k \geq 5\}$$ if you are uncomfortable with leaving the valid range for $k$ implicit. Also, you need to make sure that the minimum exists for this notation to make sense.